# error: value split is not a member of (String, String)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDD's `rdd1` and `rdd2` of type `RDD[String]`.

I have performed cartesian product on the two RDDs in scala spark

```
val cartesianproduct = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)
```

When I am performing the below code, I am getting an error.

```
val splitup = cartesianproduct.map(line => line.split(","))
```

Below is error which I am getting:

> error: value split is not a member of (String, String)

Comment: They are RDD[String]

Comment: Ok, then what is so unexpected about the error message? Pairs of type `(String, String)` indeed have no method `split`. What did you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartesian join returns `RDD` of `Tuple2[String, String]` so you have to perform map operation on `Tuple2[String, String]` not on `String`, Here is the example how to handle Tuple in map function

```
val cartesianproduct = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)
val splitup = cartesianproduct.map{ case (line1, line2) => line1.split(",") ++ line2.split(",")}
```

Comment: val splitup = cartesianproduct.map{ case (line1, line2) => line1.split(","), line2.split(",")}    I have modified the splitup Rdd .i have replaced "++" by "," . When i print splitup i am getting below as the output(this is only one line)                       ([Ljava.lang.String;@38a469af,[Ljava.lang.String;@5875d73a)

Comment: What kind of operation you want to perform inside `map` function? Above code is not correct, you can not return two array with comma.

Comment: I have ond rdd ‘game’ which contains gid, start time, end time onother rdd tweet which contains tid , tweet time.I wants to know the no of tweet between the game.I dont have any common coloumn,so i am doing cartesian product to join them together and map to split by ‘,’ . And use filter to find which tweet time is between the game time.if you have any other better solution please let me know.